# Protecting workbook except certain cells

Tags: vba, excel

I want to password protect my whole Excel workbook. Except for one sheet and one cell in another sheet. I managed to exclude a sheet. But in sheet("Voorblad") I want only one cell (D5) to be unprotected.

When I try to incorporate something with Range("D5") it fails.

```
Sub Beveiliging_Bestand()

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name <> "Inputdata" And _
       Sheet.Name <> "Voorblad" Then
        Sheet.Protect (Password = "kpi")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the way to keep your cell unlocked should be something like:

```
worksheets("Voorblad").range("D5").locked = false
```

after that you protect your sheets